# Contours in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, contour

I am having some trouble understanding contours.

What I have understood so far is that `contour`s are a way to represent a 3d figure in a 2d plane. It does so by plotting a function of 2 variables as curves along which the function has same value.

Now if I do:

```
z=[1 4; 10 7];
contour(z);
```

I get this:

[image]

I read the documentation and it says:

> contour(Z) draws a contour plot of matrix Z, where Z is interpreted as
>   heights with respect to the x-y plane. Z must be at least a 2-by-2
>   matrix that contains at least two different values. The x values
>   correspond to the column indices of Z and the y values correspond to
>   the row indices of Z. The contour levels are chosen automatically.

Thus for `x=1,y=1: z=1`, `x=2,y=1: z=4` and so on. However I can't understand how to interpret this as the `contour` plot shown above.

And if I write:

`contour(X1, X2, vals, [0.5 0.5], 'b');` where `X1`, `X2` and `vals` are equal sized matrices and `vals` is a matrix of only `0`s and `1`s. I can't understand what does the argument `[0.5 0.5]` do. I read the documentation which states:

> contour(Z,v) draws a contour plot of matrix Z with contour lines at
>   the data values specified in the monotonically increasing vector v. To
>   display a single contour line at a particular value, define v as a
>   two-element vector with both elements equal to the desired contour
>   level.

and I am unable to understand this statement.

Comment: Try `hold on;z=[1 4; 10 7]; contour3(z);surf(z,'facealpha',0.5)` to understand what those lines mean visually. `contour3` draws the lines in 3D instead of squeezing them

Comment: last argument 'b' is color e.g. r is red, b is blue

Answer (score 4):

The problem of the first contour is that there are just 4 values. Try something like

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = 0:0.1:10;
z = sin(x') * cos(y);
contour(z)
```

For the second thing, this means that if you want to see just particular contours, input them as vector v. In the example above:

```
contour(z, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
```

will show contour lines of 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3.
To have a single contour line, you can't have just (z, 0) but require (z, [0,0])

Comment: The above code gives error. So I instead tried `z = sin(x) .* cos(y);` and it still gives error.
And what does this mean `contour(z, [0, 1, 2, 3]) will show contour lines of 0, 1, 2 and 3.`? Does it mean it will show contour lines where `z=0` or `z=1` or `z=2` or `z=3`?

Comment: @shiva Sorry, forgot the transpose.

Comment: @shiva Yes, it will show contour lines just where z=0, 1, 2 or 3. Not a line where z=0.5 for example.
Those numbers are chosen stupidly and won't show anything of value, you should instead try 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3.

Comment: It means that `contour(X1, X2, vals, [0.5 0.5], 'b');` this shouldn't display any line as `vals` has only `0`s and `1`s, but it does show a line.

Comment: @shiva There is no exactly 0.1 value in that sin/cos example either, but Matlab will still draw a contour. If one value is above the specified value and the other is below, contour line goes somewhere between these 2 values.